# Trying to setup iptables properly

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, iptables, nat

I have `dummy0` interface on my machine. I need to forward its port `10456` towards `loopback` port `10456` which is forwarded via [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to some remote endpoint (very convinient). I have never done any routing tasks before, so this one is tough for me.

I asked ChatGPT for advice and it told me that first of all I need to setup bidirectional NAT rules. First for packages incoming to `dummy0` and second for packages incoming to `loopback`. It gave me the following prompt for PREROUTING and POSTROUTING chains respectively:

`# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i dummy0 -p all --dport 10456 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:10456`

`# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o dummy0 -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 10456 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1`

I've read in man and learned from ChatGPT about all options, except `--dport`. Why in both cases do I need to use this options? I am confused because I thought the letter 'd' here states for 'destination'. And also why do I need to specify `--to-source` option when I have already specified out interface? Can you help me to figure out with this?

Comment: These rules are not related to each other –they would be for incoming and outgoing *connections* respectively, in a 1:1 NAT setup. You don't need to explicitly set up bidirectional rules for just DNAT; iptables' conntrack will handle return packets automatically.

Comment: Possibly a rant but I'd put advice from ChatGPT slightly below Wikipedia searches on accuracy. Not a horrible starting place but general google searches and searches specific to SE sites are more reliable. Searching for prerouting on unix.stackexchange.com returns almost 2k hits. superuser.com has about 1.2k hits.

Comment: @user1686 Sorry for confusion. I saw this word (bidirectional) somewhere on related resources in this context and used it here, but I implied that I need to specify DNAT and SNAT or, as you said, 1:1 NAT.

Comment: @A.B Actually this is the way this supposed to work. I send packets to `dummy0` and receive responses from it. I have assigned local ip address to it.